# How do I start retracking a git repository?

Tags: git

I have a git repository which is present on Github. I have the same repository on a remote server with same file structure. Things happened and on my remote server the `.git` directory was deleted.

Is there a way I can change my repository on the remote server to track the one on Github again with the repository on Github as `origin`? **After doing it, I want the repository on remote server behave exactly like a clone of the one on Github**.

I can not remove the repository from remote server and clone it from Github again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I was able to do it. It involves creating a temporary `master` branch on remote server and then replacing it with `origin/master`

```
git init
git remote add origin <url/to/origin>
git fetch -a
```

At this point you'll have a bunch of untracked files. We'll now make a commit and create a `master` branch on remote server which will be different from one on Github.

```
git add .
```

You probably don't want to stage all the files to the commit and keep them untracked instead. Use `git reset -- </path/to/file/to/unstage>` to unstage those files or directories.

```
git status # Check the files that you're going to commit.
git commit # Create a temporary master branch for now.
```

Now rename the master branch and create another `master` that tracks `origin/master`

```
git branch -m master temp-master # Rename the just created master
git branch --track master origin/master # Track origin/master in master
```

Now remove the `temp-master`

```
git checkout master
git branch -d temp-master # You might need to use -D
```

Check that everything is correct

```
git log
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use on your remote server:

```
git remote set-url origin <your github remote url>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
git init
git remote add origin <remote-url>
git pull
```

1. Since `. git` folder is deleted, `git init` will initialise the git repo again in the remote server
2. Adding `origin` would help you track the local repo with the one in github
3. Once `origin` is added, changes are pulled from github.

Comment: since .git folder got removed, 'git init' would initialise the git repo and then second command can be issued to track the origin

Comment: I didn't understand that. I understood that the remote repo he is tracking to got its .git folder deleted. I removed my comment.

Comment: I updated my question a little bit. I want the repo on remote server to behave like a clone of the Github repo. The commands in this answer will simply add a `remote` with the name of origin which points to Github. How would I pull in changes and branch information from Github?

Comment: After adding 'remote', do 'git pull'. This will pull the changes from the github to repo in remote server.

Comment: maybe you can edit your answer to include the explanation you gave in the comments

Comment: @learner It does not answer my question. After `git init` it is a new git repo and has a bunch of unstaged files as expected. I added the remote `origin`. When I do `git pull` it fails with an error. `error: Entry '<path/to/filename>' would be overwritten by merge. Cannot merge.` Doing a `git pull --force` results in same error. I could make a commit on remote server. But it'll create a new `master` branch which will have different commit history than the one on Github.